# Warning: sizeof (): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable, On products pages

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, tags, count, warnings

I have a WooCommerce WordPress Theme installed.

I'm getting an error that public users can see, So I need to fix it ASAP.

The error is shown on all products pages, Here is the error:

```
Warning: sizeof (): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

Here is the related code:

```
global $product, $post, $smof_data;
$cat_count = sizeof(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat'));
$tag_count = sizeof(get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_tag'));
```

The error is from the last line of the above code.

I could do something like checking if that `get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_tag')` is an array first, Else assign it to empty `''` or 0.

But not sure if this would affect other code.

How to solve this issue without affecting any other related code?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at [`get_the_terms` Codex page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/). We can find there that this function may return:

> (array|false|WP_Error) Array of WP_Term objects on success, false if
>   there are no terms or the post does not exist, WP_Error on failure.

So your code will work correct only in one case - when the function returns an array of terms.

But it may also return a `WP_Error` if any error occurs or `false` if there are no terms for that post in given taxonomy.

So yes - you should always include proper error checking in your code. It may look like this:

```
global $product, $post, $smof_data;
$cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
$cat_count = ( !empty( $cats ) && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ) ? count($cats) : 0;
$tags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_tag');
$tag_count = ( !empty( $tags ) && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) ? count($tags) : 0;
```